# A funtion which takes a list and add their position in racket programming

Tags: racket

I want to write a function that takes as input a list of elements and returns a list with elements and their position after. For example, if the input to the function is `(list x y z )` then it will return `(list x 1 y 2 z 3)`. I wrote code which can reverse first two items, but I can't handle this one, can anybody help?

Comment: Can you write a function that takes a list and builds a copy of that list, i.e., `(copy-list '(x y z))` --> `(x y z)`? Now keep a counter `n` which is incremented as the input is traversed, and add the value of the counter to the new list as you build it. You might try using a helper function inside of the main function to keep the counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an implementation using a recursive helper function. I think the code is self-explanatory.

```
(define (index-list-rec lst start)
  (if (empty? lst) empty
      (cons (first lst) (cons start (index-list-rec (rest lst) (add1 start))))))

(define (index-list lst) (index-list-rec lst 1))
```

Comment: (define index-list-rec (λ (lst start)
                         (cond 
                         ((empty? lst) empty)
                         (#t
                        (cons (first lst) (cons start (index-list-rec (rest lst) (add1 start)))))
                            )))
(index-list-rec '(a b c) 1) ,                                                                                                         
I did with by bind it with lamda, that's my university recuirement , thank you so much. I got  zest from your code.

Comment: Can I use another data structure for same problem? Like set, instead fo list?

Comment: @Sujon But in racket, sets would also be represented as lists. Could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: The question is something like  use a different data structure instead of a list as input that would make simplier above function, so I am confuse which data structure I can use here , which will make it more simple.